# Dataweave 2.2 What's the difference between takeWhile and filter?

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Arrays
output application/json
var arr = [0,1,2,4,3]
---
arr filter $ <= 2
```

and

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Arrays
output application/json
var arr = [0,1,2,4,3]
---
arr takeWhile $ <= 2
```

They both give the same results.  Is there any difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hi Dale there is a difference takeWhile will stop taking elements with the first element that the condition is not satisfied that is not the case of filter so for this example  **[0,2,4,3,1]**

**With TakeWhile**

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Arrays
output application/json
var arr = [0,2,4,3,1]
---
arr takeWhile $ <= 2
```

**Returns:**

```
[
  0,
  2
]
```

**With Filter**

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Arrays
output application/json
var arr = [0,2,4,3,1]
---
arr filter $ <= 2
```

**Returns:**

```
[
  0,
  2,
  1
]
```

Answer (score 0):

**takeWhile** : Selects elements from the array while the condition is met but stops the selection process when it reaches an element that fails to satisfy the condition.

Script

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Arrays
output application/json
var arr = [0,2,4,3,1]
---
arr takeWhile $ <= 2
```

Output

```
[
  0,
  2
]
```

---

**filter** : To select all elements that meet the condition, use the function.
Script

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Arrays
output application/json
var arr = [0,2,4,3,1]
---
arr filter $ <= 2
```

Output

```
[
  0,
  2,
  1
]
```